# How can i Join 2 tables and add them with join query

Tags: sql-server

I'm asking the question again, I've forgotten something.
I would like to combine these queries as a result. One table is the archive older than 30
Days the other table is younger than 30 days. I use a tool in Wordpress for the SQL query. I have already made many queries there. Unfortunately I cannot create a UNION query there. Is there a simple solution?

Yonger 30 days

```
SELECT 
SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
,SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
,SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
,SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
,SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion 
,MONTH(anmeld_dat) as Monat
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[ade_protokoll] p
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
AND satz_art = 'E'
AND YEAR(begin_ts)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)
```

and the query older 30 days

```
SELECT 
SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
,SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
,SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
,SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
,SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion 
,MONTH(anmeld_dat) as Monat
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll] p
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] b
ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
AND satz_art = 'E'
AND YEAR(begin_ts)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)
```

[image]

Comment: Youn can join your 2 queries on date + p.masch_nr, that would give the result you want

Comment: `GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)` Careful what you assume. Do your tables contain multiple years of data? For example, the sums you generate for November will include all years - not just 2021. And learn the very significant different between UNION and UNION ALL.

Comment: Indeed grouping by `EOMONTH` is probably better. Given that you are only using `SUM`, you can remove the inner grouping and only use grouping on the outside

Comment: I use a plugin for wordpress that can process SQL. I have already created a lot of SQL queries there. Unfortunately, it cannot process the union query. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the total by month, you just need to add one more level of aggregation and group it by month.

```
SELECT t.masch_nr,
       t.Monat,
       SUM(t.SOLLRüsten) AS SOLLRüsten,
       SUM(t.SOLLProduktion) AS SOLLProduktion,
       SUM(t.SOLLZuschlag) AS SOLLZuschlag,
       SUM(t.ISTRüsten) AS ISTRüsten,
       SUM(t.ISTProduktion) AS ISTProduktion
FROM  
(SELECT p.masch_nr
        ,SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
        ,SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
        ,SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
        ,SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
        ,SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion 
        ,MONTH(p.anmeld_dat) as Monat
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[ade_protokoll] p
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
  ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
     AND satz_art = 'E'
GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)
UNION 
SELECT p.masch_nr
       ,SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
       ,SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
       ,SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
       ,SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
       ,SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion 
       ,MONTH(p.anmeld_dat) as Monat
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll] p
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] b
  ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
      AND satz_art = 'E'
GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)
) t
GROUP BY t.masch_nr, t.Monat
ORDER BY t.Monat
```

Answer (score 0):

If `UNION` can't be used, then maybe a `FULL JOIN` can help.

```
WITH CTE_OLDER AS ( -- Older than 30 days
    SELECT 
      SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
    , SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
    , SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
    , SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
    , SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion 
    , MONTH(anmeld_dat) as Monat
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll] p
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] b
    ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
    WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
    AND satz_art = 'E'
    AND YEAR(begin_ts)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)
)
, CTE_YOUNGER AS ( -- Younger than 30 days
    SELECT 
      SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
    , SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
    , SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
    , SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
    , SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion 
    , MONTH(anmeld_dat) as Monat
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[ade_protokoll] p
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
    ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
    WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
    AND satz_art = 'E'
    AND YEAR(begin_ts)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(anmeld_dat)
) 
SELECT 
  COALESCE(old.SOLLRüsten, young.SOLLRüsten) AS SOLLRüsten
, COALESCE(old.SOLLProduktion, young.SOLLProduktion) AS SOLLProduktion
, COALESCE(old.SOLLZuschlag, young.SOLLZuschlag) AS SOLLZuschlag
, COALESCE(old.ISTRüsten, young.ISTRüsten) AS ISTRüsten
, COALESCE(old.ISTProduktion, young.ISTProduktion) AS ISTProduktion
, COALESCE(old.Monat, young.Monat) AS Monat
FROM CTE_OLDER AS old
FULL JOIN CTE_YOUNGER AS young
  ON young.SOLLRüsten = old.SOLLRüsten
 AND young.SOLLProduktion = old.SOLLProduktion
```